# Visual studio 2017 есть ли способ дебажить web запросы?

Tags: c#, xnet, visual-studio-2017

Использую в своём C# проекте библиотеку xNet. Возникла потребность посмотреть что передаёт данная библиотека в интернет без установки сторонних приложений. Для примера хотелось бы посмотреть данные такого запроса:

```
using xNet;
//
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    request.UserAgent = Http.FirefoxUserAgent();
    request.AddUrlParam("name", name).AddUrlParam("password", password);
    var content = request.Post("http://ru.stackoverflow.com");//что он отправил?
}
```

Хотелось бы иметь инструмент, который был бы похож на дебагер запросов от Firefox. Может кто-нибудь знает как это сделать далеко не отходя от visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы пишете бот для сайта, то вам надо знать что отправляет не только ваш бот, но и сайт - формы, AJAX, чтобы все это в точности повторить, поэтому отладка кода не совсем корректное решение, более правильно использовать сниффер - Fiddler, Wireshark, Charles, в нем можно все сравнить до последнего символа.
Если же занимаетесь полноценным реверс-инжинирингом приложения, и нужно например понять где отправляется запрос с нелегальной передачей конфиденциональных данных на китайский сервер, то используется именно отладка кода, как в другом ответе, причем в отличие от сниффера она позволяет легко перехватить или просто заблокировать отправку запроса и получение ответа.
А вообще-то, нужно и то, и другое, часто неясно каким образом формируется параметр HTTP, и приходится работать с кодом.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать Watch Window - `Debug->Windows->Watch`. Правой кнопкой  мыши по объекту `request -> Add Watch`. Ставишь breakpoint и в окне Watch можно посмотреть свойства объекта:

[image: Watch Window]